# ASP - How to calculate total hour and minutes within time range

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I need to prepare a yearly management report to show the total overtime (OT) work hours and minutes of all staff within time range and month.

The time format in ms sql 2000 database is as follows:

Each record will contains the FROM date & time and TO date & time

[image]

The report layout is as follows:

[image]

I had no idea how to divide and calculate the total hours & minutes within the time range as each OT records will overlap several time range and date.

Please help. Thanks.

Joe

Comment: Possibly it would make more sense to have ranges like `00:00 – 00:59`, `01:00 – 01:59` etc. rather than  `00:01 – 01:00`, `01:01 – 02:00` etc. At least, the former is more common than the latter (I think).

Answer (score 1):

The SQL [DateDiff function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258269%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) can be used to compute the number of minutes, i.e.

```
declare @fromDT datetime
declare @toDT datetime
set @fromDT = '10/22/2011 18:30'
set @toDT = '10/22/2011 22:45'

select @fromDT,@toDT,DATEDIFF(mi,@fromDt,@toDt),
    ltrim(str(DATEDIFF(mi,@fromDt,@toDt)/60))+':'+
    ltrim(str(DATEDIFF(mi,@fromDt,@toDt)%60)) as HoursMin
```

Returns

```
StartTime                   End Time            Mins    HoursMin
2011-10-22 18:30:00.000 2011-10-22 22:45:00.000 255     4:15
```

Comment: thanks. if the ot record start from 2011-01-01 09:00 to 2011-01-01 11:30. how can i add 1 hr for 09:01-10:00, 1 hr for 10:01-11:00, 30min for 11:01-11:30 for the yearly report ?